# Trying to figure out the @media queries css content of the slider of this website

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am not able to get the cover to fully expand when browser size is below 750. I'm new to bootstrap.

This is the reference website I'm using to understand.

https://choosemypc.net/

## CSS

```
.slide-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
/* Not using now
.carousel-caption {
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 300px;
  }
*/
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .snippet {
    max-width: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.3;
    left: 10%;
    top: 3%;
    bottom: 3%;
  }
  .snippet-content {
    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px){
  .snippet {
    max-width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    left: 0%;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 5%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    opacity: 0.3;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

  .snippet-content {
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
}
```

This is the Css of the html

## HTML

```
<div class="slide-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">       
        <div class="row carousel-holder">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel-generic" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <%= image_tag("Ram.jpg", alt: "Ram Image", class: "slide-image img-responsive")%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <%= image_tag("System.jpg", alt: "Graphiccard Image", class: "slide-image img-responsive")%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <%= image_tag("Motherboard.jpg", alt: "Motherboard Image", class: "slide-image img-responsive")%>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-generic" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-generic" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="snippet">
                    <div class="snippet-content">
                        Content of the snippet.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the html.

Please check out the website link I've sent and suggest changes.
I need the snippet to be responsive just like in the website.

Comment: Can you link to your code?

Comment: just added, please take a look. @SakoBu

Comment: Without the html it's tough to tell. Are you basically trying to get the cover photo to be responsive?

Comment: yea, i need it to be responsive, just like the website i have linked.

Comment: Added the html , Please take a look. @SakoBu

Comment: So is it the images in the slider you want as cover photos? What's the deal with the snippet?

Comment: Ah ok, saw your note... well it's not exactly the same as the site. That site has the cover image plus the parallax effect. Where it stays put and and the rest of the site scrolls over it... probably position: fixed... also you can't have a fixed width... background-size: cover...

Comment: can u suggest how, I'm kinda new to bootstrap.

Comment: It has nothing to do with bootstrap it's just CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would suggest:

If you want the image to be a cover image (fill the screen as in your example link) look into:

```
background-size: cover;
```

If you want the same parallax effect look into:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

You can't have a max-width... it defeats the purpose...

See here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

And here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

Comment: But position: fixed wasn't what I was looking for. position: absolute did the job.

Comment: Ok great. That second link I gave is a good resource for that parallax effect... please accept the answer so that others may benefit as well...@gundergobi